# jmeter finding max sustainable throughput

Tags: load-testing, jmeter

I would like to use Jmeter to keep sending requests at the maximum sustainable interval - where the number of running threads (displayed before the / sign in the top right corner) stay constant e.g. 2. Currently I need to manually experiment by changing the number of threads during a large ramp up time. I need to do this after each change on the server. Is there an automated way to find this max. throughput?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what do you mean by "unanswered requests".

There is [Auto Stop Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) which can stop JMeter test if response time exceeds some pre-defined value or latency is bigger than expected or error rate is more than pre-defined threshold.

When the test is stopped by the listener a special environment variable: `auto_stopped` is being created with the value of `true` so you can use it for checking whether test has been stopped in script for setting the [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) code.

Auto Stop listener can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: I have changed "unanswered requests" to "running threads". I hope it's clearer now.  Auto Stop Listener does not seem to be a good choice since it can't watch the number or running threads and simply stops at the criteria instead of reducing throughput.